# "Mathematical Etymology" of adherent points and limit/accumulation points

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

We see most objects across disciplines are decently self explanatory like shear stresses "shear", groups "group", transistors "transit". Under this context, what is the "mathematical etymology" of fundamental objects identified in Topological spaces i.e., adherent points and limit/accumulation points. Are these objects doing anything that gives them the name they have been given? If so what are they "doing". What is the "Tao" of these objects? :). Thank You.

Comment: See [Limit point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) for an illustrative diagram showing "accumulation".